# Conjugate points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose $(M,g)$ is a two dimensional Riemannian manifold. Let $\gamma:(-\delta,\delta)\to M$ be a geodesic segment and suppose that $\gamma(0)$ is not conjugate to any other point in $(-\delta,\delta)$. Is it true that there always exists a solution to the Jacobi equation along $\gamma$ that is non-vanishing anywhere along $\gamma$?

Thanks,

Comment: I guess you mean orthogonlal Jacobi field to $\gamma$;otherwise $J=\gamma'$ solves your problem. For orthogonal Jacobi field the answer is no, in the unit sphere you can take $\delta$ arbitrary close to $\pi$ so, you geodesic has length almost $2\cdot\pi$ --- there is no Jacobi equation orthogonal to γ that is non-vanishing anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The example in Anton's comment above shows that the result fails if one assumes only that the conjugate radius of each point along $\gamma$ is at least $\delta$. I'll add only that the result is true if the focal radius of each point along $\gamma$ is at least $\delta$ (see [here](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/pages/journals/items/ajm/content/vols/0021/0001/a004/index.html) for the definition of the focal radius). In that case, every Jacobi field $J$ along $\gamma$ satisfying $J(0) \neq 0$ and $\nabla_{\gamma'} J(0) = 0$ is nowhere vanishing.